# ２つのテーブルに登録してできたidを、それぞれお互いのテーブルのカラムにセットするSQLを１回でできますか？

Tags: mysql, sql

2つのテーブルがあります。一つはアイテムテーブル、もう一つはパーツテーブルです。
アイテムデータを登録するアイテム画面の入力項目にタイプがありtypeが”abcde”の時にだけパーツテーブルとアイテムテーブルに登録し、それ以外の値の時はアイテムのみするのですが、この２つのテーブルはお互いの主キーを持っています。
一回のsqlでアイテムテーブル、パーツテーブルに登録して登録した結果のidをそれぞれのテーブルのpart_idとitem_idに登録することはできますでしょうか？

今、実装しているのはアイテムテーブルをまず登録して、登録してできたデータのidを取得し、パーツテーブルのデータにitem_idをセットし、パーツデータの登録し、その結果できたデータのidを取得し、最後にアイテムテーブルのpart_idを更新するような処理を考えているのですが、１回のsqlでこれを実現することは可能でしょうか？

#### アイテムテーブル

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | int(10) unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| name | varchar(255) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| price | int(11) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| part_id | int(10) unsigned | YES |  | NULL |  |
| type | varchar(255) | YES |  | NULL |  |

#### パーツテーブル

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | int(10) unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| item_id | int(10) unsigned | NO |  | NULL |  |
| name | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| number | varchar(255) | YES |  | NULL |  |

Comment: 複数のパーツで構成されるアイテムが存在する場合、アイテムテーブルの `part_id` はどうなるのでしょうか？ また、あるパーツが複数のアイテムで使われている場合も同様です。アイテムとパーツが 1 対 1 に対応しているという事でしょうか？

Comment: argusさん　コメントありがとうございます。　はい、こちらはアイテムとパーツが１：１で対応しております。画面は一覧になっておりまして、この一覧の１行がアイテムの１データになります。この１行の中にタイプという設定がプルダウンでありまして、abcdeという文言を押した時に、パーツの入力項目が入力可能になるという感じです。なのでパーツの方は必ずitem_idを持ちますが、アイテムの方はpart_idを持つデータと持たないデータが存在します。

Comment: そうなりますと、パーツテーブルの `id` はアイテムテーブルの `id` と同じにしても良いのではないでしょうか。もしくはパーツテーブルを持たずに、アイテムテーブルに例えば `part_name` と `part_number` というカラムを追加して `part_id` は削除してしまっても良いかと思いますが。。。(パーツを持たない場合は `part_name`, `part_number` は `NULL`)

Comment: SQLでは複数のテーブルを参照することはできても、更新できるのは一度に１テーブルだけです。１回のSQLで実現したい理由は何でしょうか？ 「初歩的なこと」とのことなので、もしかしてトランザクションをご存じないとか？

Comment: コメント遅れましてすみません。使用しているエンティティバインディングフレームワークの仕様の為結合しているモデルがそれぞれのキーを持っている仕組みでしたので、このような変な質問をさせていただきました。実際はSQLではなくjsでの実装となりまして、アイテムテーブルの登録で取得したアイテムキーをパーツに設定して登録し、できたパーツキーを再度アイテムに更新という実装で解決いたしました。ご親切なご回答ありがとうございました。m(_ _)m

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607570/how-to-simplify-my-sql-requests マルチポスト

Answer (score 1):

コメントより

> 使用しているエンティティバインディングフレームワークの仕様の為結合しているモデルがそれぞれ‌​のキーを持っている仕組みでしたので、このような変な質問をさせていただきました。
>
> 実際はSQLではなくjsでの実装となりまして、アイテムテーブルの登録で取得したアイテムキーをパーツに設定して登録し、できたパーツキーを再度アイテムに更新という実装で解決いたしました。ご親切なご回答ありがとうございました。 - [通りすがりのおっさん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/15499/%E9%80%9A%E3%82%8A%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8A%E3%81%A3%E3%81%95%E3%82%93)